# What is the div equivalent element in Nativescript

Tags: nativescript

I am trying to wrap some elements to provide styling and i do not see any element that can be used as a container.

What is supposed to be used in such a case?

Also kindly link to the available css properties in Nativescript as i was unable to find a list of available css properties.

Comment: Here are the supported CSS properties: http://docs.nativescript.org/ui/styling#supported-properties

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While styling elements is useful, I think the answer to your question would be to use `StackLayout` or `GridLayout` depending on what you want to do.

Comment: Basically everything in NativeScript is "stylable". So Layouts suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

`StackLayout` or `GridLayout` are commonly used, but not best practice. Nesting many `StackLayout` or `GridLayout` will slow the performance of your app, so use them sparingly. Use `Label` more often. Also, a handy tip is using `FormattedString` for nesting some paired elements.

Example:

```
<Button class="-primary p-8">
    <FormattedString>
        <Span text="&#xf007;" class="fas t-18"></Span>
        <Span text=" Different " color="red"></Span>
        <Span text="colors in "></Span>
        <Span text=" Button " backgroundColor="green" color="whitesmoke"></Span>
    </FormattedString>
</Button>
```

https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-components/formatted-string